# Impose a wait between two submits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which does an AJAX action when submitting. Just after a user has submitted the form, I'd like to impose a minimal waiting time of 5sec to post one more time.

What the better way ? I made this script (doesn't work but I guess idea is here):

```
$("form#submit_under_wall"+array[1]).submit(function() {

    var submit_timestamp=0;
    var c = new Date();
    var now = ISODateString(c); 

    if(now-submit_timestamp>5){

         var d = new Date();
         var timestamp_message = ISODateString(d); 
         submit_timestamp = timestamp_message ;

          //AJAX ACTION             

    }else{ alert("Wait 5sec between each post."); }


return false;   
});
```

Comment: you should really impose this on the serverside if you are looking for a 'better way'. Anything you do on the client will be circumventable by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesnt work because the timestamp is reset every time they submit, you need to move submit_timestamp outside of the function. Also, that 5 should probably be 5 * 1000

something like this (not tested):

```
var submitTime = (new Date()).getTime() - 5000; //let user submit if he clicks within 5s of page load
$("form#submit_under_wall"+array[1]).submit(function(e) {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    if(now-submitTime > 5000){
         submitTime = (new Date()).getTime();
         //AJAX ACTION             
    } else {
        alert("Wait 5sec between each post.");
    }
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Minor improvement: you force the user to wait if he ever tries to submit for the first time in the first 5s. Could happen in a copy/paste/submit scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most standard way would be to use Javascript native `setTimeout` method.

```
var last_action;

function ajax_action() {
  last_action = Date.getTime();
  // AJAX STUFF
}

$("form#submit_under_wall"+array[1]).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Sexier than 'return false'
  if(last_action != undefined) {
    setTimeout(ajax_action, Date.getTime()-last_action); // Wait for 5s before doing the action 
  } else {
    ajax_action();
  }
});
```

Comment: he doesnt want to submit later, he wants to make sure you can only submit once every 5 seconds.

Comment: still no good. imagine they click the button 10 times fast, the first will cause an ajax action now, the next 9 will queue up to happen 5 seconds later, in about 5 seconds, there will be 9 ajax actions (and NOT 5 seconds apart)

Comment: You are right. I started editing it again then realised that your answer is the right one. So I'll just +1 yours.

Answer (score 0):

use `window.setTimeout()`

1. Wrap what you want to do in a function (eg `function foo (){ alert('test'); }`)
2. Call it with a 5 second delay `setTimeout(foo,5000)`